# Multiple allocation and nil pointer assignment memory concepts

Tags: ios, objective-c, automatic-ref-counting

1. What happens when I allocate init an object multiple times?

For example:

```
{
  nssstring * samplestring ;
  samplestring = [[nsstring alloc]init];
  samplestring = [[nsstring alloc]init];
}
```

Is the memory address that samplestring points on first allocation a leak after this code `block` execution?

Is this normal or a BAD CODING PRACTICE.
How Does ARC handles the first memory allocation after this bloc execution.

2.How is the above code different from

```
{
  nssstring * samplestring;
  samplestring = [[nsstring alloc]init];
  samplestring = nil;
}
```

`Nil` is an object. Right ? So it seems here too that the first `samplestring` memory allocation would behave similar to the code block in 1. Or does `nil` have special significance in memory management.

Finally if I want to use the same object name should I follow 1 or 2.

I am asking this question from my phone so please excuse the formatting, and in case this is a duplicate.

Comment: No, `nil` is not an object. It is "zero".

Comment: So you mean to say that nil is equivalent to 0. That means some int zero = nil; is valid code?

Comment: Yes, `int zero = nil` is technically valid but don't ever use it that way. `nil`, by convention, should only be used for Objective-C pointers. Use `0` for non-pointers.

Comment: Hmm.. I got that. Thanks .

Comment: `Nil` is cool in another way, that you can send a message to `nil` and it will not crash, e.g., `[nil someMessage];`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using ARC then there is no leak in either of those two cases.

In the first example you create a pointer.  Then you create an object in memory and tell the pointer to point to it.  Then you create another object in memory (at a different memory location) and tell the pointer to point to it.  ARC will see that nothing points to the first allocation anymore and mark the memory location as garbage and re-usable.  ARC adds in the `retain]` and `release` calls for you based on when the objects are pointed to or not (have a retian count of 1 or more).

Your second example is pretty much the same.  You create a pointer.  then you create an object and tell the pointer to point to it.  then you tell the pointer to point to nothing (zero).  At that point you have nothing pointing to the memory location that you created, ARC sees that and marks the memory as garbage/re-usable.

In some ways the second example is better because then when you run analyze with xcode it will see that you set the pointer to nil and any further uses of it without reassignment will be flagged as errors (if they didn't cause your app to crash in the first place).  But it's really a matter of opinion.

Comment: ok I got this, but then another question strikes me. If everything is so well handled by the arc then what could be a case of leak. Seems that the arc will not lose track of allocated memory so when exactly will a leak happen in arc?

Comment: A simple answer to that is a class that has a variable of it's own class type.  You create an object `class *object = [[class alloc] init];`.  The create an internal reference, `object.variable = object`.  Now the class points to intself internally.  If you say `object = nil` arc still sees that object has a reference count of 1 even though you can no longer touch it in code.  Leak.  there are others too, but that is the easiest to explain.

Answer (score 2):

For 1, when you re-assign an object pointer, ARC will destroy the old object.  Similarly, if the object goes out-of-scope, it will be destroyed

```
{
    NSString * samplestring ;
    samplestring =[ [nsstring alloc]init];    // first object created
    samplestring =[ [nsstring alloc]init];    // first destroyed, second created
}    // second object destroyed
```

For 2, this is pretty much the same story, except there is nothing to destroy when the symbol goes out-of-scope:

```
{
    NSString * samplestring;
    samplestring =[ [nsstring alloc]init];    // first object created
    samplestring =nil;                        // first object destroyed
}
```

As for *Finally if I want to use the same object name should I follow 1 or 2.*, it doesn't really matter, however 2. is redundant as ARC will manage the object lifetime correctly.

And finally, `nil` is not an object, it's a *nil pointer*, i.e. a pointer to nothing.